# How to programmatically access wordnet hierarchy?

Tags: nlp, wordnet, word-sense-disambiguation, jaws-wordnet

Suppose for any word I want to access its IS-A parent value and HAS-A value then is it possible using any api?

Answer (score 11):

You can use the python API of the [Natural Language Toolkit](http://nltk.org/). In Wordnet, the IS-A-relation is called *hypernym* (opposite: *hyponym*) and the HAS-A relation is called *meronym* (opposite: *holonym*).

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
book = wordnet.synsets('book')[0]
book.hypernyms()
>>> [Synset('publication.n.01')]
book.part_meronyms()
>>> [Synset('running_head.n.01'), Synset('signature.n.05')]
```

I also found the [NodeBox Linguistics](https://nodebox.net/code/index.php/Linguistics) API easier to use:

```
import en
en.noun.hypernym('book')
>>> [['publication']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use commandline. The command is "wn book -hypen" to get the hypernyms of the noun book. For meronyms, use the command "wn book -meron".
Also the -o option gives the synset offset.
[Here](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/documentation/wn1wn) is the link for further information.

Answer (score 1):

Shameless plug:

I'm writing a Scala library to access WordNet.  While not all the similarity measures have been implemented, all the word senses and relations are available.  I use it for my research so its in active development.

```
import com.github.mrmechko.swordnet._

SKey("book",SPos.Noun)
//> List(SKey("publication%1:10:00::"))

SKey("publication%1:10:00::").getRelation(SRelationType.hypernym) //Hypernyms

SKey("publication%1:10:00::").getRelation(SRelationType.hyponym) //Hyponyms etc
```

[SWordNet](https://github.com/mrmechko/SWordNet) is available on GitHub and Sonatype